# Storing variable into session asp.net c#

Tags: c#, session

I am creating a website with multiple users and I am scared that by using session it will erase the data in session once a new user login. For example, user A login and will be able to see he/she username A. However, if a new user login which is user B, will the new user B see the username A or username B?

```
public void getusername()
{         
    String user = Convert.ToString(txtusername.Text);
    string strConn = Convert.ToString(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"]);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select username from tblusers where user1 ='" + user + "' ", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    Session["user"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Until you write to the session again then yes the user will see the previous users name, have a look at the MSDN on session https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: Are you talking about the same PC/Browser for user A & B?

Comment: @ChrFin thats what I assumed, hence why I linked the MSDN article on the SessionState

Comment: I will be hosting into domains like godaddy as my project requires me to do hosting for my website. The issue here is will user A see username B using different browser/PC?

Comment: @KelvinOng you need to have a look at and understand `sessions` the article linked in my comment is the official Microsoft documentation....

Comment: ok thanks will have a look at it